# How to remove row which contains blank cell from csv file in Java

Tags: java, csv, data-cleaning

I'm trying to do data cleaning on dataset. by data cleaning i meant removing the row which containes `NaN` or duplicates values or empty cell. here is my code

dataset look like this:

```
Sno Country     noofDeaths
1                32432
2    Pakistan     NaN
3    USA          3332
3    USA          3332
```

excel file image:
[image]

```
public class data_reader {
    String filePath="src\\abc.csv";
    public void readData() {
         BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
          
            HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(!line.contains("NaN") || !line.contains("")) {
                        if (lines.add(line)) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }   
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }   
    }
```

it is working fine for NaN values and duplicates rows but not for empty cell, please help how to do this.

```
!line.contains("")
```

this is not working.

Comment: All strings contain the empty string. What does an "empty cell" actually look like in your CSV file? Incidentally, I would strongly advise using a proper CSV library to parse CSV files.

Comment: I Uploaded the dataset format, pleasee check

Comment: Is the data space delimited? Tab delimited? It definitely isn't comma separated.

Comment: please check the excel file image i uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition **!line.contains("")** - doesn't make sence because every string contains empty string.

**General suggestions:**

- don't hard code file-path, code must be reusable;
- use try with resources;
- camel-case names.

```
public class DataReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataReader().readData("src\\abc.csv");
    }

    public void readData(String filePath) {
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            HashSet<String> lines = new HashSet<>();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!line.contains("NaN")) {
                    for (String cell: line.split(",")) {
                        if (!cell.isBlank()&&lines.add(cell)) {
                            System.out.print(cell + " ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working, it tried this too ```line.trim().isEmpty()```

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: I uplaoded the excel file image too, please check that

Comment: ```Sno,Country,noofDeaths
1,,32432
3,USA,3332``` it print this output on my side

Comment: It should not print the sno 1 line becuase country value is empty there

Comment: You misunderstand, there is no 'cells', solid lines only. You have split strings by comma

Comment: yes, i got it now! thank you

Comment: check the code now

Comment: thank you so much, it works what i required.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this is a pretty easy problem to solve. Given a CSV file with an empty row

```
foo,bar,baz
1,One,123
,,
2,Two,456
3,Three,789
```

You can read the lines and define an empty line as one which contains empty strings separated by commas. You could read the contents of the file, store the populated lines into a string buffer, and then save the contents of the buffer once the empty lines are extracted out. The code below accomplishes this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String file ="test.csv";
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String line = null;
     StringBuilder sbuff = new StringBuilder();
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] tokens = line.split(",");
         if (containsText(tokens)) {
             sbuff.append(line + "\n");
         }
     }
     reader.close();
     System.out.println(sbuff.toString());
     // save file here
}
    
public static boolean containsText(String[] tokens) {
    for (String token: tokens) {
        if (token.length() > 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After running the code, the output is:

```
foo,bar,baz
1,One,123
2,Two,456
3,Three,789
```

This same code can be used to determine if a cell is empty with a simple method:

```
public static boolean isCellEmpty(String[] tokens) {
    for (String token: tokens) {
        if (token.isBlank())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```